# Tried to use TinyMce in cakephp but it is not working

Tags: cakephp, tinymce

I tried to use the TinyMce plugin in cakephp but the editor is not loading but the helpers are. Even after extracting the files to the plugins folder and adding the codes in bootstrap.php file its not working.

Helper:

```
 <?php  
App::uses('AppHelper', 'View/Helper'); 

class TinymceHelper extends AppHelper { 

    // Take advantage of other helpers 
    public $helpers = array('Js', 'Html', 'Form'); 

    // Check if the tiny_mce.js file has been added or not 
    public $_script = false; 

    /** 
    * Adds the tiny_mce.js file and constructs the options 
    * 
    * @param string $fieldName Name of a field, like this "Modelname.fieldname" 
    * @param array $tinyoptions Array of TinyMCE attributes for this textarea 
    * @return string JavaScript code to initialise the TinyMCE area 
    */ 
    function _build($fieldName, $tinyoptions = array()){ 
        if(!$this->_script){ 
            // We don't want to add this every time, it's only needed once 
            $this->_script = true; 
            $this->Html->script('tiny_mce/tiny_mce', array('inline' => false)); 
        } 

        // Ties the options to the field 
        $tinyoptions['mode'] = 'exact'; 
        $tinyoptions['elements'] = $this->domId($fieldName); 

        // List the keys having a function 
        $value_arr = array(); 
        $replace_keys = array(); 
        foreach($tinyoptions as $key => &$value){ 
            // Checks if the value starts with 'function (' 
            if(strpos($value, 'function(') === 0){ 
                $value_arr[] = $value; 
                $value = '%' . $key . '%'; 
                $replace_keys[] = '"' . $value . '"'; 
            } 
        } 

        // Encode the array in json 
        $json = $this->Js->object($tinyoptions); 

        // Replace the functions 
        $json = str_replace($replace_keys, $value_arr, $json); 
        $this->Html->scriptStart(array('inline' => false)); 
        echo 'tinyMCE.init(' . $json . ');'; 
        $this->Html->scriptEnd(); 
    } 

    /** 
    * Creates a TinyMCE textarea. 
    * 
    * @param string $fieldName Name of a field, like this "Modelname.fieldname" 
    * @param array $options Array of HTML attributes. 
    * @param array $tinyoptions Array of TinyMCE attributes for this textarea 
    * @param string $preset 
    * @return string An HTML textarea element with TinyMCE 
    */ 
    function textarea($fieldName, $options = array(), $tinyoptions = array(), $preset = null){ 
        // If a preset is defined 
        if(!empty($preset)){ 
            $preset_options = $this->preset($preset); 

            // If $preset_options && $tinyoptions are an array 
            if(is_array($preset_options) && is_array($tinyoptions)){ 
                $tinyoptions = array_merge($preset_options, $tinyoptions); 
            }else{ 
                $tinyoptions = $preset_options; 
            } 
        } 
        return $this->Form->textarea($fieldName, $options) . $this->_build($fieldName, $tinyoptions); 
    } 

    /** 
    * Creates a TinyMCE textarea. 
    * 
    * @param string $fieldName Name of a field, like this "Modelname.fieldname" 
    * @param array $options Array of HTML attributes. 
    * @param array $tinyoptions Array of TinyMCE attributes for this textarea 
    * @return string An HTML textarea element with TinyMCE 
    */ 
    function input($fieldName, $options = array(), $tinyoptions = array(), $preset = null){ 
        // If a preset is defined 
        if(!empty($preset)){ 
            $preset_options = $this->preset($preset); 

            // If $preset_options && $tinyoptions are an array 
            if(is_array($preset_options) && is_array($tinyoptions)){ 
                $tinyoptions = array_merge($preset_options, $tinyoptions); 
            }else{ 
                $tinyoptions = $preset_options; 
            } 
        } 
        $options['type'] = 'textarea'; 
        return $this->Form->input($fieldName, $options) . $this->_build($fieldName, $tinyoptions); 
    } 

    /** 
    * Creates a preset for TinyOptions 
    * 
    * @param string $name 
    * @return array 
    */ 
    private function preset($name){ 
        // Full Feature 
        if($name == 'full'){ 
            return array( 
                'theme' => 'advanced', 
                'plugins' => 'safari,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template',
                'theme_advanced_buttons1' => 'save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect',
                'theme_advanced_buttons2' => 'cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor',
                'theme_advanced_buttons3' => 'tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen',
                'theme_advanced_buttons4' => 'insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak',
                'theme_advanced_toolbar_location' => 'top', 
                'theme_advanced_toolbar_align' => 'left', 
                'theme_advanced_statusbar_location' => 'bottom', 
                'theme_advanced_resizing' => true, 
                'theme_advanced_resize_horizontal' => false, 
                'convert_fonts_to_spans' => true, 
                'file_browser_callback' => 'ckfinder_for_tiny_mce' 
            ); 
        } 

        // Basic 
        if($name == 'basic'){ 
            return array( 
                'theme' => 'advanced', 
                'plugins' => 'safari,advlink,paste', 
                'theme_advanced_buttons1' => 'code,|,copy,pastetext,|,bold,italic,underline,|,link,unlink,|,bullist,numlist',
                'theme_advanced_buttons2' => '', 
                'theme_advanced_buttons3' => '', 
                'theme_advanced_toolbar_location' => 'top', 
                'theme_advanced_toolbar_align' => 'center', 
                'theme_advanced_statusbar_location' => 'none', 
                'theme_advanced_resizing' => false, 
                'theme_advanced_resize_horizontal' => false, 
                'convert_fonts_to_spans' => false 
            ); 
        } 

        // Simple 
        if($name == 'simple'){ 
            return array( 
                'theme' => 'simple', 
            ); 
        } 

        // BBCode 
        if($name == 'bbcode'){ 
            return array( 
                'theme' => 'advanced', 
                'plugins' => 'bbcode', 
                'theme_advanced_buttons1' => 'bold,italic,underline,undo,redo,link,unlink,image,forecolor,styleselect,removeformat,cleanup,code',
                'theme_advanced_buttons2' => '', 
                'theme_advanced_buttons3' => '', 
                'theme_advanced_toolbar_location' => 'top', 
                'theme_advanced_toolbar_align' => 'left', 
                'theme_advanced_styles' => 'Code=codeStyle;Quote=quoteStyle', 
                'theme_advanced_statusbar_location' => 'bottom', 
                'theme_advanced_resizing' => true, 
                'theme_advanced_resize_horizontal' => false, 
                'entity_encoding' => 'raw', 
                'add_unload_trigger' => false, 
                'remove_linebreaks' => false, 
                'inline_styles' => false 
            ); 
        } 
        return null; 
    } 
}
```

I used the following codes in my view file:

```
<?php 
echo $this->Html->script('/TinyMCE/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js', array(
'inline' => false)); ?>



    <script type="text/javascript">

        tinyMCE.init({

            theme : "advanced",

            mode : "textareas",

            convert_urls : false,

            theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,blockquote,separator,strikethrough,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright, justifyfull,bullist,numlist,undo,redo,link,unlink",

            theme_advanced_buttons2: "",

            theme_advanced_buttons3: "",

            theme_advanced_buttons4: "",

            theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",

            theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left"

        });

    </script>
```

I added this code in my controller:

```
public $helpers = array('Tinymce');
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it... I just inserted it manually and the problem was in setting the path to the js file.